# How to properly use STDERR_FILENO?

Tags: c, unix, macros, system-calls, file-descriptor

Can any one give me an example of how to properly use `STDERR_FILENO` from the `<unistd.h>` header file?

Mainly I want to learn how to write error messages to `STDERR_FILENO`.

I used `STDOUT_FILENO` in the past to write to a certain file so I am wondering about `STDERR_FILENO`.

```
write(STDOUT_FILENO, buff, buffSize);
```

Any ideas or quick examples are greatly appreciated. 
Thanks in advance for your help.

P.S: I would be grateful if you can post for me one line or two of actual code to see how to properly use it.

Comment: There is no difference between `STDOUT_FILENO` and `STDERR_FILENO` (except the underlying stream obviously). If you know how to use `STDOUT_FILENO`, you know how to use the other.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example;

```
char *msg = "This is my message"; /* The actual message*/
int len = strlen(msg);  /* the byte length of the string */
write(STDERR_FILENO, msg, len);
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you try `write(STDERR_FILENO, buff, buffSize);` ?

Why don't you use `<stdio.h>` ?

Comment: Yes you are right. I don't know though what shall fill in place of "buff" and "buffSize". Like my error message will fit in the (buff) part and the size of it in the (buffSize)? I am not so sure about it. Could you provide me with a small example in one line or two?

Comment: But you really should use `<stdio.h>` and learn about `printf` if you are such a newbie...

Comment: I am using them already. I just wanted to confirm the usage of it. Thanks though for your advice - (+1 for your clear answer).